# Does UITextField consume touch events?

Tags: iphone, events, uitextfield

My view controller has UITextField object as a subview. The controller is set as target to handle the text field's UIControlEventTouchUpOutside event.
I'm trying to use this event handler for dismissing keyboard when the text field becomes first responder, but it seems to be never called. Delegate methods like textFieldShouldReturn work just fine.

Why the text field object doesn't send action message to the target? I tried this scheme for bunch of all touch events, but no luck.. Or do I have to subclass UITextField somehow to be able to catch this event?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITextField for sure responds to those event to handle cursor positioning and so on.  It might not 'forward' those event to its parent.  If you need to intercept those, you can subclass UITextEvent and catch those event yourself (of course do not forget to call [super  blablabla] in order to keep the standard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It just doesn't respond the UIControlEventTouchUpOutside event. I am sure it will respond UIControlEventValueChanged event. I think you can put a transparent custom UIButtom as background view, and if any touchInSideUp in the UIButtom, you can dismissing keyboard as desired.

Answer (score -1):

It responds to the same events as UIButton. Take a look in IB. Also you may consider using UITextFieldDelegate method

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Comment: Does not respond to UIControlEventTouchUpInside